# SQL Inner joining a column from two tables with a single user id

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I've been trying to get this SQL query running for a while now and can't seem to get the last little bit going.

The backend database to all this data is a Drupal install with data spread out across a number of modules, so I need to do a lot of joining to get a certain view table set up that I need for a third-party application.

It's hard to explain the entire schema, but here's the sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68df0/2/0

So basically, I have a userid which I map to a profile id through a join. Then I need to use that profile ID to pull the related data about that profile from two other tables. (there should only be one row with each pid in each of the other tables)

So in the end, I would like to see a table with username, othername, and key_id.

I got the first two pieces in there, but just can't seem to figure out how to join in the othername, and keep getting null.

The server is running MySQL.

Thanks guys!

Comment: In the last LEFT JOIN section, it should be `LEFT JOIN other_name
ON profile_link.pid=other_name.pid;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LEFT JOIN other_name
ON profile_link.pid=other_name.pid;
```

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo in the sqlfiddle, it now works in the fiddle, but still doesn't in my actual production environment, so I'm not sure where the problem is. I guess I'll just have to play around with it until it works.  

Edit: Ohhh, I just realized that profile_link actually has two rows for each user, one which links to keys, and the other which links to  the names, so I'm going to need to write up a more complex query for that. This is the right solution to the question I posted on SO though. Thanks.